# serialize Kafka messages with confluent registry under Flink 1.9.1

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, confluent-schema-registry

is it possible to publish message to Kafka serialized with `KafkaAvroSerializer` by Confluent. I'm using Flink 1.9.1 have saw that some development is going on newer version of flink-avro (1.11.0) but I’m stick to the version.

I would like to use the newly introduced `KafkaSerializationSchema` for serializing the message to Confluent schema-registry and Kakfa.

Here I have currently a class that is converting a class type `T` to avro but I want to use the confluent serialization.

```java
public class KafkaMessageSerialization<T extends SpecificRecordBase> implements KafkaSerializationSchema<T> {
    public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaMessageSerialization.class);

    final private String topic;

    public KafkaMessageSerialization(String topic) {
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    @Override
    public ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> serialize(T event, Long timestamp) {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final Schema schema = event.getSchema();
        final DatumWriter<T> writer = new ReflectDatumWriter<>(schema);
        final BinaryEncoder binEncoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(outputStream, null);

        try {
            writer.write(event, binEncoder);
            binEncoder.flush();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            LOG.error("serialization error", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return new ProducerRecord<>(topic, outputStream.toByteArray());
    }
}
```

The usage is quite convenient `.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer<>(SINK_TOPIC, new KafkaMessageSerialization<>(SINK_TOPIC), producerProps, Semantic.AT_LEAST_ONCE))`

Comment: It seems that the code has been added to flink: https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/8371/files but it's not available in the library

Answer (score 2):

I am in the same situation and based on your solution i wrote this class. I have tested it with Flink 1.10.1.

```java
public class ConfluentAvroMessageSerialization<T extends SpecificRecordBase> implements KafkaSerializationSchema<T> {

    public static final org.slf4j.Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConfluentAvroMessageSerialization.class);

    final private String topic;
    final private int schemaId;
    final private int magicByte;

    public ConfluentAvroMessageSerialization(String topic, String schemaRegistryUrl) throws IOException, RestClientException {
        magicByte = 0;
        this.topic = topic;

        SchemaRegistryClient schemaRegistry = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegistryUrl, 1000);
        SchemaMetadata schemaMetadata = schemaRegistry.getLatestSchemaMetadata(topic + "-value");
        schemaId = schemaMetadata.getId();

        LOG.info("Confluent Schema ID {} for topic {} found", schemaId, topic);
    }

    @Override
    public ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> serialize(T event, Long timestamp) {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final Schema schema = event.getSchema();
        final DatumWriter<T> writer = new ReflectDatumWriter<>(schema);
        final BinaryEncoder binEncoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(outputStream, null);

        try {
            byte[] schemaIdBytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(schemaId).array();
            outputStream.write(magicByte); // Confluent Magic Byte
            outputStream.write(schemaIdBytes); // Confluent Schema ID (4 Byte Format)
            writer.write(event, binEncoder); // Avro data
            binEncoder.flush();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Schema Registry Serialization Error", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return new ProducerRecord<>(topic, outputStream.toByteArray());
    }
}
```

Confluent has a propertary format with a magic Byte and the schema id (4 Byte). For more information please check https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#wire-format